# How to write a SQL Server query to show comma separated child table columns left join with parent table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I am using a SQL Server database, that has tables as defined below. I need to write a T-SQL query to show comma-separated child table columns left join with parent table.

Parent table

```
pid   pname
------------
p1    Ana
p2    Bana
p3    Cana
```

Child table

```
Cid   pid   cname              gender
-------------------------------------
c1    p1    AAA-Ana            M
c2    p1    BBB-Ana            M
c3    p1    CCC-Ana            F
c4    p2    MMM-Bana           M
c5    p2    NNN-Bana           M
c6    p3    RRR-Cana           F
c7    p3    SSS-Cana           F
c8    p9    ZZZ-orphan-child   M
```

[image: resultant query output should be as shown below]

Comment: You can do this using string_agg. Could you please paste the actual data and not the sample to enable people here to provide a fiddle with query.

Comment: Which version of sql-server are you using ?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU20) (KB4541283) - 14.0.3294.2 (X64)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested you can use below query with String_agg and Case in SQL server 2017 onwards.

```
SELECT A.PID, A.pname, 
STRING_AGG( CASE WHEN GENDER = 'M' THEN [cname] END, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY B.CID) CNAME_MALE,
STRING_AGG( CASE WHEN GENDER = 'F' THEN [cname] END, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY B.CID) CNAME_FEMALE,
COUNT(CASE WHEN [gender] = 'M' THEN 1 END)  AS MALE_COUNT , COUNT(CASE WHEN [gender] = 'F' THEN 1 END)  AS FEMALE_COUNT
FROM TABLE_PARENT A INNER JOIN Table_child B
ON(A.PID = B.PID) GROUP BY A.PID, A.pname order by a.pid;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join the tables and then count grouping by pid and pname, that will get you the amounts. For the string concatenation I like to use the stuff function:

```
select  P.pid,
        P.pname,
        cname_Male = (stuff((Select ', ' + cname
                                 from childTable 
                                 where pid = P.pid and gender = 'M'
                                 for xml path ('')), 1, 2, '')),
        cname_Female = (stuff((Select ', ' + cname
                                from childTable 
                                where pid = P.pid and gender = 'F'
                                for xml path ('')), 1, 2, '')),  
        MaleCount = (Select count(1) From childTable where pid = P.pid and gender = 'M'),
        FemaleCount = (Select count(1) From childTable where pid = P.pid and gender = 'F')
from parentTable P
Join childTable C ON C.pid = P.pid
group by P.pid, P.pname
```

Output:

[image]